# Dark spots on metallic objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

[image: D]

As title states I am having the problem shown in the image. Any idea why this is happening and any solution?

Comment: If you mean the cube it looks like a wrong UV mapping.

Comment: please show your UV map for the cube